# Текст и вложения, какой формат файла сделать?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть приложение на Qt представляющее из себя форму с текстовыми и числовыми полями, а так же возможностью загружать вложения (картинки, пдф и иные файлы весом до 500МБ и по сути не ограниченного количества).

Сейчас данные из формы сохраняются в JSON (бинарное представление Qt) и нужно ко всему этому сохранить вложения.

Думал сохранять данные формы в один файл, а вложения "вливать" во второй файл, прописывая в первом файле в соответствующих вложениям полям offset этого вложения из второго файла.

Таким образом (в сравнении с данными и вложениями в едином файле) при пересохранении текста, если его объем будет увеличен, не придется создавать новый файл и копировать туда все вложения, коих может быть вплоть до пары гигабайт, но два файла вместо одного видится мне не практичным (пользователь захочет записать файл на флешку и забудет "базу" вложений и тю-тю).

Как лучше сохранять всё это? Иметь два файла для единой сущности не представляется мне "красивым". Нормально ли что при каждом сохранении будет создаваться временный файл, в него писаться данные и копироваться все вложения ("шерстеть" диском на пару гигов каждый раз по-моему не "культурно")?

Comment: Лучше просто хранить ссылки на файлы "вложений". Если пользователь удалит вложение - его проблема. Значит, он сам счел файл ненужным, так ему ваша программа и напишет: извините, но вот это вы сами удалили. Если он просто перебирал файлы на диске и что-то переместил, то можно предложить интерфейс найти перемещенное.

Comment: В данном случае такое поведение будет считаться не корректным, т.к. заполняется стандартизированная форма предприятия. При передачи файла другому пользователю - он должен получить доступ ко всем данным имеющим отношение к этой форме. Таково ТЗ.

Comment: Понял. Все равно, сотни мегабайт туда-сюда гонять это как-то не очень. Может, стоит сделать что-то типа хранилища для всех этих вложений. Чтобы принимающий пользователь получал ссылку и, например, права на просмотр.

Comment: Записывайте все в архив (zip или 7z). Складывайте отдельные вложения - в подпапки, чтобы избежать конфликтов имен. Пользователю не обязательно говорить, что это файл архива, а для отладки - удобно.

Comment: @Chorkov Да согласен архив в данном случае был бы удобен, но по сути остается тот же вопрос множественных дисковых операциях при пересохранении. Т.е. допустим записали документ и вложения, в следующий раз удалили одно вложение и изменили документ - по сути тут будет создан новый архив, в него записаны вложения из прошлого файла и затем произведена замена файла. Или zip\7z умеют оперировать указанным файлом без создания временного файла? Или может я за это вообще зря парюсь(пересоздание архива с чтением данных из старого)?

Comment: Прочитал описание формата на вики, суть понял, не понятно осталось лишь поведение по каким критериям архиватор должен решать когда файл просто пометить удалённым, а когда нужно "избавиться от мусора"